# SqlAlchemy query failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I ran the following code `Lessons.query.all()`
But I got the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "lessons" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM lessons
^

[SQL: SELECT lessons.id AS lessons_id, lessons.title AS lessons_title, lessons.subtitle AS lessons_subtitle, lessons.img AS lessons_img, lessons.body AS lessons_body, lessons.questions AS lessons_questions, lessons.tags AS lessons_tags
FROM lessons]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Lessons class:

```
class Lessons(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.TEXT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    goes_to = db.column(db.TEXT)
    title = db.Column(db.TEXT, unique=True)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.TEXT)
    img = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    questions = db.Column(db.TEXT, db.ForeignKey("questions.content"))
    tags = db.Column(db.TEXT)
```

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you create the tables using ```db.create_all()```?

Comment: I was about to ask you if you applied the migration after you changed the schema?

Comment: @Detlef yes I did, it shows up when I connect to the database.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database in your `flask-sqlalchemy` code as when you connect manually?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes I did

Comment: what is the database you are using? MySQL, Postgres, SQLite,....? show us the connection part to your database. - Do you have other tables you correctly dealt with?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you have other tables you correctly dealt with?

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein I checked just now and I realized that other tables are causing errors

Comment: What is your `search_path` set to and does it include the schema where the tables live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was that other tables were causing errors that stopped the database from working.